# Why Maven dependency exclusion would not cause compile error?

Tags: java, maven, classpath, transitive-dependency

Newly exposed to **Maven**, I can understand the use case of the `<exclusion>` tag, but not sure why it wouldn't cause compile error:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
...
```

Is this only possible only when you have another direct dependency on maven-core? otherwise, compile error should happen. (assuming `maven-core` is used somewhere in `maven-embedder`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different possibilities:

1. As Carl said: Check your `dependency:tree` if the dependency is not pulled in from somewhere else.
2. It is possible that `maven-core` is not used at all, even if `maven-embedder` indeed uses it: Assume e.g. that `maven-embedder` has two classes A and B. You only use A, but `maven-core` is only used by B. Then (if A and B do not use each other), your project might be entirely independent of `maven-core`. (A side remark: some jars should logically be two separate jars, but where merged together by whatever reason - in our example, one should think about putting A and B in separate artifacts).
3. It is possible that transitive dependencies are not necessary at compile time, but are used at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You are excluding that artifact from that specific dependency, but it could be getting pulled in from another dependency.  Using something `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=maven-core` should show you what else is introducing the dependency.  [The Maven Enforcer plugin can also help exclude transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/banTransitiveDependencies.html).

Comment: this is definitely possible, JF Meiler's answer covers more possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

The error will not thrown in the compile time, It will thrown in run time if you use any feature depends on maven-core